# Issues with Count as an element in array conflicting with count. Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm currently writing a PoSH script to snapshot our VMware servers. Running into a hitch as I'd like for the script to remove the oldest snapshot when more than 3 are taken.
I have put the servers I want to snap and the count of current snapshots into an Array, however when I use the logic of

```
    IF ($variable | where-object {$_.count -gt 3}) {
        write-host $_.name }
```

The script returns nothing for the script block, when I run it manually $variable.count returns the count not the value of the element in the array (I guess because of the membertype). 
I.e. if I have two items in the array it returns a value of 2 instead of the number in the count column i.e. 5.
I'm probably doing something very stupid but the PowerCLI object for snapshots uses count as the element name.
Any ideas gratefully received.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The example you pasted taken literally means: "Evaluate elements in `$variable` that have a count greater than three. If this evaluates to true, then write the name property of the `$_` (current pipeline object) to host." Which doesn't seem quite what you wanted, because it:

1. asserts that each element in your `$variable` is itself a collection, by checking for counts on the current pipeline object and not the collection as a whole.
2. causes the if statement to never evaluate to true because your elements aren't collections, and thus don't have counts to be greater than anything.
3. uses the current pipeline object variable `$_` outside of a pipeline.

---

This simple example is probably closer to what you want. For the sake of example, lets remove properties and just use a simple string array. It will print the name of the last item in a collection if the collection's size is greater than 3:

```
PS C:> $arr = "test1","test2","test3","test4"
PS C:> if($arr.Count -gt 3) { Write-Host $arr[-1] }
test4
```

Feel free to build on this; I'm not sure from your question body of some more specific details about which array element specifically you want to remove. For example, if you want to remove the first element instead of the last, you'll want to use `$arr[0]` to select that element.

Comment: Thanks, it's OK. I decided to rerun the cmdlet with a select/where with a count -gt 3 into a second array which works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for your reference:

```
$maxtasks = 4

$snaps = get-vm | get-snapshot -name "before power down"

$i = 0
while($i -lt $snaps.Count){
 Remove-Snapshot -Snapshot $snaps[$i] -RunAsync -Confirm:$false
 $tasks = Get-Task -Status "Running" | where {$_.Name -eq "RemoveSnapshot_Task"}
 while($tasks.Count -gt ($maxtasks-1)) {
 sleep 30
 $tasks = Get-Task -Status "Running" | where {$_.Name -eq "RemoveSnapshot_Task"}
     }
     $i++
}
```

As long as there are more than 3 - then the script will sleep, once there are less than 3 it will increment *$i* by 1 and will continue to remove the next snapshot.
Refer the link for your reference. [Throttle Snapshot](http://technodrone.blogspot.com/2010/03/removing-esx-snapshots-en-mass.html)

And if you want to remove based on number of days, then use this approach: 
Here the span is of 30 days.

```
$oneMonthAgo = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
Get-VM | Foreach-Object {
Get-Snapshot -VM $_ | Foreach-Object {
if($_.Created -lt $oneMonthAgo) {
Remove-Snapshot $_ -Confirm -WhatIf
}}}
```

**Note**: Be very careful on Remove-Snapshot cause it could potentially do a lot of damage

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of VMware limitations which is why my snapshot script will not allow more than 3 current snapshots.

Comment: What I tried to explain is you can use either way to deal what I have mentioned in the answer to deal the situation. Anyways , for a simple solution I would like you to check also one more thing-- the last element of the array by using `array[-1]`